# Parallel and distinct

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

As I understand it, there are three possibilities for linear systems; no solution, unique solution, or infinitely many solutions.

(i) For unique solution, there is only one intersection, a point where the given lines meet/intersect.

(ii) For infinitely many solutions, we get parameters, meaning any value on the said parameters works just fine because the lines occupy same space/line.

(iii) For unique solution, we don't have any intersection, the lines are parallel, no more no less, none of the lines are little off or whatnot, they are exactly parallel meaning they never ever meet.

Now, what got me confused is, when I was reading about a linear system with no solutions I noticed they used the following words to describe the result: "Parallel and distinct". Why would they use the word "distinct", because if e.g. two lines are parallel then they are distinct anyway? (or am I missing something, and if so are there cases where two parallel lines aren't distinct?) The said problem is x+y=4 and 0=-6, this troubles me because this is the only instance where they've used the word "distinct" while on other problems they simply say "parallel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably say parallel and distinct just to rule out the possibility of having two of the same line. If you have two copies of the same line, they are probably considered by the authors to be parallel, but are definitely not distinct.

If you have 0=-6 as part of the system, then you've come to a contradiction, which means that you started with two "parallel" distinct lines.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I understand correctly then (ii) can be considered parallel lines as well, right?

Comment: Because my understanding of "parallel" is, e.g. two lines that don't occupy same space and never meet, i.e. parallel.

Comment: My thoughts are that the authors have used misleading language, and that by parallel, they mean sharing the same slope. Perhaps they are just trying to further clarify by saying distinct.

After thinking about it, though, I agree with you. They should not need to say distinct as well. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Either way, in order to avoid the whole confusion with what it means to be parallel, it's useful to just consider the cases as:

(i) Lines/planes meet at a point.
(ii) Lines/planes meet on an entire line/plane.
(iii) Lines/planes do not all meet.

Comment: Actually, that is much better! I will use your wording, it is easier to understand and not confusing at all! Thank you!